# Speed up HTML5 Canvas pixel rendering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, color-blending

I am designing a Photoshop-style web application running on the HTML5 Canvas element. The program runs well and is very speedy until I add blend modes into the equation. I achieve blend modes by merging each canvas element into one and combining each pixel from each canvas using the right blend modes starting from the bottom canvas.

```
for (int i=0; i<width*height*4; i+=4) {
    var base = [layer[0][i],layer[0][i+1],layer[0][i+2],layer[0][i+3]];
    var nextLayerPixel = [layer[1][i],layer[1][i+1],layer[1][i+2],layer[1][i+3]];
    //Apply first blend between first and second layer
    basePixel = blend(base,nextLayerPixel);
    for(int j=0;j+1 != layer.length;j++){
        //Apply subsequent blends here to basePixel
        nextLayerPixel = [layer[j+1][i],layer[j+1][i+1],layer[j+1][i+2],layer[j+1][i+3]];
        basePixel = blend(basePixel,nextLayerPixel);
   }
   pixels[i] = base[0];
   pixels[i+1] = base[1];
   pixels[i+2] = base[2];
   pixels[i+3] = base[3];
}
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imgData,x,y);
```

With it calling blend for different blend modes. My 'normal' blend mode is as follows:

```
var blend = function(base,blend) {
    var fgAlpha = blend[3]/255;
    var bgAlpha = (1-blend[3]/255)*base[3]/255;
    blend[0] = (blend[0]*fgAlpha+base[0]*bgAlpha);
    blend[1] = (blend[1]*fgAlpha+base[1]*bgAlpha);
    blend[2] = (blend[2]*fgAlpha+base[2]*bgAlpha);
    blend[3] = ((blend[3]/255+base[3])-(blend[3]/255*base[3]))*255;
    return blend;
}
```

My test results in Chrome (yielding some of the best out of the tested browsers) was around 400ms blending three layers together on a canvas 620x385 (238,700 pixels).

This is a very small implementation as most projects will be larger in size and include more layers which will make the execution time skyrocket under this method.

I'm wondering if there is any faster way to combine two canvas contexts with a blend mode without having to go through every pixel.

Comment: What is `nextLayerPixel`? How do you create it and why do you change it in the `blend` function (second parameter)?

Comment: I first excluded that part to show the functionality without the extra code making it messy, but now I added it in. 'nextLayerPixel' simply is a variable that refers to the same pixel in each layer. So with a project with 3 layers and on pixel x:30, y:20, it will grab the bottom layer pixel at 30,20 then middle 30,20 and then top 30,20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create so many 4-value-arrays, it should go much faster when using the existent memory. Also, you might want to use the [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your `layer` array, this seems exactly what you need. However, using no functions at all might be another touch faster - no creation of execution contexts needed. The following code will invoke the blend function only for each layer, not each pixel * layers.

```
var layer = [...]; // an array of CanvasPixelArrays
var base = imgData.data; // the base CanvasPixelArray whose values will be changed
                         // if you don't have one, copy layer[0]
layer.reduce(blend, base); // returns the base, on which all layers are blended
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imgData, x, y);

function blend(base, pixel) {
// blends the pixel array into the base array and returns base
    for (int i=0; i<width*height*4; i+=4) {
        var fgAlpha = pixel[i+3]/255,
            bgAlpha = (1-pixel[i+3]/255)*fgAlpha;
        base[i  ] = (pixel[i  ]*fgAlpha+base[i  ]*bgAlpha);
        base[i+1] = (pixel[i+1]*fgAlpha+base[i+1]*bgAlpha);
        base[i+2] = (pixel[i+2]*fgAlpha+base[i+2]*bgAlpha);
        base[i+3] = ((fgAlpha+base[i+3])-(fgAlpha*base[i+3]))*255;
//                           ^ this seems wrong, but I don't know how to fix it
    }
    return base;
}
```

---

Alternative solution: Don't blend the layers together in javascript at all. Just absolutely position your canvases over each other and give them a CSS `opacity`. This should speed up the displaying a lot. Only I'm not sure whether this will work together with your other effects, should they need to be applied on multiple layers.

Comment: Very good answer. Took me a while of reading documentation to get the reduce function to actually work with my code. I'm still going to have to figure something out because the speed is only down to 180ms on the fastest browsers and nearly 1000ms for slower browsers. Mobile browsers are over 1 second. This won't be able to work for my application and I might have to take blend modes out unless there is another way to edit larger areas at a time

Comment: How often do you need to call this blend function?

Comment: The blend function is called each time one of the layers is modified as long as one of the layers in the project has a mode other than normal. It will only call on the area that has been modified, but if a user is moving a large object or painting using a large brush then it will have to do large areas very quickly and will be called every time a graphic is moved. This isn't just mousedown/mouseup. It also includes mousemove which will be called numerous times each second. This could work if I could get it to at least 5fps (200ms) but I don't see that happening in the slower browsers.

Comment: With how many layers do you work, does that have an impact? You could just reduce all of them excluding the currently active one to a single pixel data array, and then only blend the active into that precalculated each time.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. The only thing is that I don't know of a way to calculate blend modes starting at the top layer. So I would only be able to calculate the blend of all layers below the layer. Because blends rely on all layers below the current layer it would only help if the layer being modified was one of the higher up layers. And the number of layers can change depending on the project.

Comment: OK, if the blend function is really not associative, you might go for the stacked canvas approach (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally these type of massive pixel manipulation is sped up by running them on the GPU, rather than on the CPU.
Unfortunately canvas doesn't have support for this but you could potentially implement a workaround using [SVG Filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html). This would allow you to use hardware accelerated blend modes (feBlend) to blend two images together.
If you render your layers to two images and then refer these images in your SVG you could make this work.

Here is a nice illustrated overview how this could work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx (for IE10 but applies to any browser which supports SVG Filters)